About Json format and Player Prefs
I'm making an Offline RPG game in Unity. I want to save some things in my game. I have heard of two recording systems for this, one is PlayerPrefs and the other is to save in json format. PlayerPrefs is simple and easy to hack, and it does not work on all devices in json format. I do not consider the json format because it cannot be played on every device, and since the game is offline, I do not see any harm in doing it with PlayerPrefs. What do you think, what would be better for me to do?

What do you mean when you say JSON cannot be used on every device? You may be interested in past Q&A about saving in Unity. The big thing to watch for is that PlayerPrefs can be wiped if the player uses a system restore point on Windows, unlike your own custom save file. Whether that's a concern for your situation is something you'll have to judge for yourself.

And there is not much of a difference in how easy it is to manipulate either PlayerPrefs or json. You could even store a json string in the PlayerPrefs if it makes sense

In a video I watched, it was said that not every software supports the language, but most of them do. Someone also wrote the following in a forum: "Also, in some forums, it has been written that saving and loading in JSON format does not work on Android devices. I would be very grateful if you could answer these questions. I could not find it by searching."

Json is a format, a way to represent data, how the data looks like. PlayerPrefs is a storing system, where you store the data.

Watch out for developing by hearsay. There's a lot of bad advice and flat-out wrong information out there on the Internet, somewhat especially in beginner Unity forums/tutorials. Unity's built-in JsonUtility works just fine on Android. The user who posted that might have been confused by the fact that you can't write to Application.dataPath on Android and need to use Application.persistentDataPath instead (which is what you should use for all platforms, some are just less strict in enforcing it, letting bad habits and bad advice spread).

I understand Thank you for the valuable information you provided. When I combine the videos I watched online and what you said, I understand better what you mean.

I've marked this thread as a duplicate of the one I linked above. If you need some help answering a question that's not covered there or in the comments above, please feel free to edit your question to focus it on that issue, then we can re-open it for new answers.

Ok. Thank you. If I have a question about this subject, I will write.
